# Using eventReactive with a rendering function

Tags: r, shiny

I've been stuck on this problem for two days now, and I would love some help from people much smarter than me. I am using a package called "shinyTable"(https://github.com/trestletech/shinyTable), and I am having a hard time manipulating it. Basically, how can I make this table change its size based on input$rows IF I click on the "submit" button?Here is a working code w/o the "submit" button:

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(shinyTable)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"),titlePanel(HTML("<h1> <font face=\"Rockwell Extra Bold\" color=\"#b42000\"><b><b>R/Econ</b></b></font> <font face=\"Lucida Calligraphy\" colsor=\"white\" >Model</font></h1>")),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel( 
                    numericInput("rows", label = h3("Number of Rows"), value = 20),
                    numericInput("cols", label = h3("Number of Columns"), value = 2)
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    htable("tbl")
                  )
                )
)
server <- function(input, output) 
{
  output$tbl <- renderHtable({
    if (is.null(input$tbl)){
      # Seed the element with some data initially
      tbl <- data.frame(list(num1=1:input$rows, 
                             num2=(1:input$rows)*20,
                             letter=LETTERS[1:(input$rows)]))
      cachedTbl <<- tbl
      print(tbl)
      return(tbl)
    } else{
      cachedTbl <<- input$tbl
      print(input$tbl)
      return(input$tbl)
    }
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now, I want the table's size to change dynamically when my input$rows or input$cols changes. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make this work. I tried the following:

```
myx<-eventReactive (input$submit, { 
  output$tbl <- renderHtable({
    if (is.null(input$tbl)){
      tbl <- data.frame(list(num1=1:input$rows, 
                             num2=(1:input$rows)*20,
                             letter=LETTERS[1:(input$rows)]))
      cachedTbl <<- tbl
      print(tbl)
      return(tbl)
    } else{
      cachedTbl <<- input$tbl
      print(input$tbl)
      return(input$tbl)
    }
  }) 
  })
```

But this doesn't work. My thought process was that if the submit button is clicked, it would recreate the table. I want input$rows to change the size of the table, but neither my changing the size nor my clicking on a submit button does anything. In fact, adding eventReactive changes the table to where it has no values, and no values can be inputted. I'm honestly lost. I tried other variations of this such as this:

```
myx<-eventReactive (input$submit, { 
    if (is.null(input$tbl)){
      tbl <- data.frame(list(num1=1:input$rows, 
                             num2=(1:input$rows)*20,
                             letter=LETTERS[1:(input$rows)]))
      cachedTbl <<- tbl
      print(tbl)
      return(tbl)
    } else{
      cachedTbl <<- input$tbl
      print(input$tbl)

    }
  })
    #-------
 # myx2<-eventReactive (cachedTbl, { 
 # })
    output$tbl <- renderHtable({
       tbl<<-myx()
        print(data.frame(tbl))#Tried and failed using myx()
        return(data.frame(tbl))

    })
```

In doing this, I thought I can make the table reactive and then pass it to renderHTable. All these attempts share the fact that I'm trying to make things reactive.

How can I make this table change its size based on input$rows IF I click on the "submit" button? Please help!

Comment: You should use rhandsontable https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable which is an evolution of shinyTable.  rhandsontable is on Cran and it is maintained. shinyTable is not.

Comment: try using `observeEvent()` instead of `eventReactive()` and I am unable to find where you have defined `input$rows`, as the code stands `input$rows` is NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. As per my comment, you should use `rhandsontable`. This package uses the same underlying JS library, `handsontable.JS`, but it is well supported and it is on Cran (disclaimer: I'm a minor contributor to this package).

The working example below is based on `rhandsontable`.  For simplicity I've only implemented the change of the number of rows.

Please take into account that I haven't implemented any type of caching mechanism, either to a global variable, or to a reactive variable, as it wasn't necessary, but it can easily be added.

This is the only example that I know of a library working in `shiny` where there is an `output$something` linked to an `input$something`.

In this case the `input$tbl` in the code refer to the table, but to be converted to a data frame it needs to be transformed by the convenience function `hot_to_r` (`handsontable` to `R`).

I am sure you are already familiar with this: you use `hot_to_r(input$tbl)` to check if the user has changed anything in the displayed table (assuming it is not read-only). `shinyTable` has a much more complicated mechanism, but it is prone to races.

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"),titlePanel(HTML("<h1> <font face=\"Rockwell Extra Bold\" color=\"#b42000\"><b><b>R/Econ</b></b></font> <font face=\"Lucida Calligraphy\" colsor=\"white\" >Model</font></h1>")),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel( 
                    numericInput("rows", label = h3("Number of Rows"), value = 20),
                    numericInput("cols", label = h3("Number of Columns"), value = 2)
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    rHandsontableOutput("tbl")
                  )
                )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data = reactive({
    if (is.null(input$tbl))  {
        DF <- data.frame(num1 = 1:input$rows, bool = TRUE, nm = LETTERS[1:input$rows],
                        dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = input$rows),
                        stringsAsFactors = F)

    } else  if(nrow(hot_to_r(input$tbl)) == input$rows) {
        DF <- hot_to_r(input$tbl)
      } else {
        DF <- data.frame(num1 = 1:input$rows, bool = TRUE, nm = LETTERS[1:input$rows],
                dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = input$rows),
                stringsAsFactors = F)
    }
    DF
  })

  output$tbl <- renderRHandsontable({
if (is.null(input$rows) | is.null(input$cols)) return()
    df = data()
    if (!is.null(df))
      rhandsontable(df, stretchH = "all")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please let me know if this works for you, else I'll do my best to change it as per your needs.

Comment: Hey Enzo , I know you're super busy, so I really appreciate you even looking at this comment. How would I compare the new data frame saved to DF to the previous DF? In other words, I want to compare the table with new user inputs with the table before the user inputted anything new?

Comment: The strategy is to compare old (unchanged) value, say `dfOld`, with new value, say `dfNew`.  There are different strategies, one is to use `which(dfOld != dfNew, arr.ind=TRUE)`, which gives you rows and cols that have changed. I'll try to see if I can add this to the code, but it will be in a day or so: sorry.